# How to get the value of the data item to use in {{if}}?

Tags: jquery-templates, knockout.js

I am trying to get the value of the data item to use in a {{if}} tag, but cannot get it to work. So, the question is how do we get that value? You can see full code here http://jsfiddle.net/epitka/BhYvh/

```
<script id="contentHeaderTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
   {{if($data.Id===1)}} Create New Order{{else}}Edit Order {{/if}}      
    <br />
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the parentheses.

```
{{if $data.Id === 1 }}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/KdqZF/

See also the [`{{if}}` template tag API page](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-if).

Comment: how to get all entity data in jquery template this $data has been useful. ${JSON.stringify($data)}

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the parentheses in that if statement. Try:
`{{if $data.Id === 1 }}`

Comment: how to get all entity data in jquery template this $data has been useful. ${JSON.stringify($data)}